# How to get memcahe usage

Tags: memory, memcached

We are using Memcache in our server for few months, Now I want to check the memory it is using?

While we are using **stats** command we got the below output.

```
STAT bytes_read 226428688048
STAT bytes_written 205477506872
STAT limit_maxbytes 1073741824
```

What this means, how we calculate the memory used?

Answer (score 0):

You can find information about Memcached stat metrics in this [Oracle documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/refman-5.0-en/ha-memcached-stats-general.html). I couldn't find it in the [Memcached wiki](https://code.google.com/p/memcached/wiki/NewStart?tm=6). I am not sure if the description is accurate though here is how I read it.

- bytes is the quantity of bytes used by Memcached **(this is what you are looking for)**
- bytes_read is the total of bytes read from Memcached
- bytes_read is the total of bytes written to Memcached
- limit_maxbytes is the maximum of bytes that can be used by Memcached

I found this [documentation](https://code.google.com/p/memcached/wiki/NewUserInternals) about how memory is used internally; it might interest you.